# Pthread ~ Function that returns a character in pthread.

Tags: c++, pthreads

Would you please give me an example function that return character from pThread. 
Say for example:
I have the following function.

```
void *consumer (void* data)
{
 for (int ii=0; ii<100; ii++)
 {
    char myVar = c;
    return (void *)myVar;
}

}
```

the above function is only for returning character values.

In the main function.

```
pthread_t c;

char result;

pthread_create(&c, 0, consumer, &pc);

pthread_join(c, (void **) &result);

cout << "Main method Consumer return" << result  << endl;
```

I know the above is not a complete piece of code. But, I hope you get the idea. I just need a demo for a function that return a character in PThread.

Thanks in advance.

-Teva

Comment: Note that your `for` loop might not do what you want, it simply ends the thread function at the first chance (`return ...`).

Comment: Thanks! You're right. I thought about that. But, this is just a pseudo code. Even if I remove the for loop and consider the following code. Still I don't get what I wanted.

Comment: #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    static void *compute_prime(void* arg)
     {
 
        char tt = "T";
        assert(arg == 0);
        return (void *)tt;
     }

     int main(void)
      {
        pthread_t thread;
    
        char prime;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread, (void **) &prime);
        printf("The returned value is", prime);
        return 0;
     }

Comment: I think you have solved your primary problem returning data from thread functions, but I still see your pseudo code `for` loop and wonder what you'll really want to achieve executing some calculation asynchronously from your main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only thing you're missing is how to correctly convert a char into a void *. Try a thread function with the following code:

```
char c = 'A';
intptr_t i = c;
return *(void **)&i;
```

And then:

```
char result;
intptr_t i;
pthread_join(c, (void **)&i);
result = i;
```

The [`intptr_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/%20stdint.h) type is an integer type with the same size as a pointer, and so this code avoids reading a pointer (4 or 8 bytes, depending on 32bit/64bit-system) into a char (1 byte). If you want to avoid the intptr_t, use something like `char arr[sizeof(void *)]; arr[0] = c;`

**Edit:**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
static void *compute_prime(void *arg) {
    char c = 'A';
    intptr_t i= c;
    return *(void **)&i;
}
int main(void) {
    pthread_t thread;
    char result;
    intptr_t i;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, (void **) &i);
    result = i;
    printf("The returned value is %c\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
The returned value is A
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT Florian Rhiem for your reply. I tried as per you mentioned and got the empty string out. I know I did some crazy mistake in my following code. Would you please correct it for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: #include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static void *compute_prime(void* arg)
{
    char c = 'A';
    intptr_t i= c;
    return *(void **)&i;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    char result;
    intptr_t i;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, (void **) &i);
    result = i;
    printf("The returned value is", result);
    return 0;
}

Comment: I'm sorry that I have a hardtime to align my code in the reply.

Comment: No problem, I just ran it through `astyle` :) I editted a working version of your code into my reply.